# Number Formatting in Thousands

Tags: c#, number-formatting

- How, for example, do I turn the number **10562.3093** into **10,562** in C#?
- Also, how do I ensure that same formatter will apply correctly to all other numbers?....
- ...For example **2500.32** into **2,500**

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string formatted = value.ToString("N0");
```

This divides your number in the manner specified by the current culture (in the case of "en-US," it's a comma per multiple of 1000) and includes no decimal places.

The best place to look for any question regarding formatting numbers in .NET would have to be here:

[Standard Numeric Format Strings (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(VS.71).aspx)

And here:

[Custom Numeric Format Strings (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
string.Format("{0:n0}", 10562.3093);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:0,0}", 10562.3093);
```

I keep this website bookmarked for these purposes: [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: Using "0,0" will prefix single digit numbers with a 0: String.Format("{0:0,0}", 2.3093); results in "02", using "#,#" instead will prevent this.

Comment: Won't work either: 0 will turn into nothing. You should use either `N0` or `#,0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 10562.3093;
x.ToString("#,0");
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:#,0}", 10562.3093);
```

Comment: Won't work either: 0 will turn into nothing. You should use either `N0` or `#,0`.

Comment: Edited, I didn't consider that case.